# Why do odds ratios from formula and R's fisher.test differ? Which one should one choose?

Tags: r, odds-ratio, fishers-exact-test

In the following example

```
> m = matrix(c(3, 6, 5, 6), nrow=2)
> m
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    5
[2,]    6    6
> (OR = (3/6)/(5/6))    #1
[1] 0.6
> fisher.test(m)        #2

    Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  m 
p-value = 0.6699
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1 
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.06390055 5.07793271 
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
 0.6155891
```

I calculated the odds ratio (#1) "manually", 0.600; then (#2) as one of the outputs of the Fisher's exact test, 0.616.

**Why didn't I get the same value?**

**Why do several ways of computing the odds-ratio exist, and how to choose the most appropriate one?**

Answer (score 15):

From the help page for `fisher.test()`:

> Note that the conditional Maximum Likelihood Estimate (MLE) rather
>   than the unconditional MLE (the sample odds ratio) is used.

Answer (score 6):

To add to the discussion here, it is useful to ask *what* exactly is conditioned on in this "conditional" likelihood. The Fisher test differs from other categorical analyses in that it considers *all* margins of the table to be fixed whereas the logistic regression model (and corresponding Pearson chi-square test which is the score test of the logistic model) only consider one margin to be fixed.

The Fisher test then considers the hypergeometric distribution as a probability model for the counts observed in each of the 4 cells. The hypergeometric distribution has the peculiarity that, since the distribution of the originating odds ratio is not continuous, you often obtain a different OR as a maximum likelihood estimate.

Comment: I don't think your answer makes it clear how this particular likelihood might arise. If you model the data-generating process with a product-binomial, say, you get a different  likelihood (& MLE) conditional on the marginal totals, from what you get if you model it with Wallenius' non-central hypergeometric distribution - the marginal totals are "considered fixed" in both cases.

Answer (score 2):

I am stuck with the same problem. I searched and searched in stackExchange and Google, and I did not find anything explicitly explaining how the odds ratio in `fisher.test()` is calculated. This is not a complete answer, but it provides something useful to the discussion.

One thing is clear, `fisher.test()` calculates a completely different odds ratio with a different (and more complicated) method.

If you write `fisher.test` in R Console and press Enter, the output will be the complete code of the function `fisher.test()`. The interesting part concerning our doubt is:

```
m <- sum(x[, 1L])
n <- sum(x[, 2L])
k <- sum(x[1L, ])
x <- x[1L, 1L]
lo <- max(0L, k - n)
hi <- min(k, m)

support <- lo:hi #Interval of definition of Hypergeometric Distribution

logdc <- dhyper(support, m, n, k, log = TRUE) #log of Hypergeometric Probability Function

dnhyper <- function(ncp) {
  d <- logdc + log(ncp) * support
  d <- exp(d - max(d))
  d/sum(d)
}

mnhyper <- function(ncp) {
  if (ncp == 0) 
    return(lo)
  if (ncp == Inf) 
    return(hi)
  sum(support * dnhyper(ncp))
}

mle <- function(x) {
  if (x == lo) 
    return(0)
  if (x == hi) 
    return(Inf)
  mu <- mnhyper(1)
  if (mu > x) 
    uniroot(function(t) mnhyper(t) - x, c(0, 1))$root
  else if (mu < x) 
1/uniroot(function(t) mnhyper(1/t) - x, c(.Machine$double.eps, 
                                              1))$root
  else 1
}
```

Well, if you

1. Define `x = matrix(c(3, 6, 5, 6), nrow=2)`
2. Run every line of the code extracted from `fisher.test` in order
3. Run `mle(x)`

You get `0.6155891`. So this is how the odds ratio in `fisher.test` is calculated. However, I do not understand the algorithm. I have not found any article explaining it, and it does not seems possible to translate it to a "simple" mathematical formula.

**EDIT:**

The odds ratio estimate obtained by `fisher.test` is the *conditional maximum-likelihood estimate* (CLME) of the odds ratio.

Given a table like this (where $C1$ is the sum of the first column, and so on):

\begin{array}{ll|l}
a_{11} & a_{12} & R_1 \\
a_{12} & a_{22} & R_2 \\ \hline
C_1 & C_2 & n 
\end{array}

The CLME odds ratio is defined as

$$ \text{arg } \max_{\psi >0} \frac{\binom{C_1}{a_{11}}\binom{C_2}{a_{12}}\psi^{a_{11}}}{\sum_{k = \max(0, R1 - C2)}^{min(R1, C1)} \binom{C_1}{k}\binom{C_2}{R_1-k}\psi^k }$$

There is no explicit formula of the CLME odds ratio, so one has to use iterative methods to find the argument of the maximum of the function. I suppose that is what `fisher.test()` does, but I don't recognize the algorithm. So I programmed one by myself:

```
OR <- function(x) {
  C1 <- sum(x[, 1])
  C2 <- sum(x[, 2])
  R1 <- sum(x[1, ])
  a11 <- x[1, 1]
  a12 <- x[1, 2]
  n <- sum(x)

  fobjetivo <- function(psi)  {
    lo <- max(0, R1 - C2)
    hi <- min(R1, C1)
    sumandosDenom <- numeric(n)
    for (k in lo:hi) {
      sumandosDenom[k] <- choose(C1,k) * choose(C2, R1-k) * psi^k
    }
    salida <- ( choose(C1, a11) * choose(C2, a12) * psi^a11 ) / sum( sumandosDenom )
    return(salida)
  }
  as.numeric(optimize(fobjetivo, interval = c(0.01, 100), maximum = T, tol = 0.00001)$maximum)
}

x = matrix(c(3, 6, 5, 6), nrow=2)
OR(x)
```

The output is `0.6052843`. Still not the same value obtained by the `fisher.test()`, but in general it appears to be closer than the sample odds ratio. I suppose the difference is explained by the different methods, by I don't know for sure.

Reference: Kenneth J. Rothman, Sander Greenland and Timothy L. Lash (2008): *Modern Epidemiology*, 3rd Edition, Lippincott-Raven Publishers, p. 257

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second question, biostats isn't my forte but I believe the reason for multiple odds ratio statistics is to account for sampling design and design of experiments.

I've found three references here that will give you a bit of understanding as to why there is a difference between conditional MLE vs unconditional for odds ratio, as well as other types.

1. [Point and interval estimation of the common odds ratio in the combination of 2 × 2 tables with fixed marginals](https://academic.oup.com/biomet/article-abstract/57/3/471/252945/Point-and-interval-estimation-of-the-common-odds?redirectedFrom=PDF)
2. [The Effect of Bias on Estimators of Relative Risk for Pair-Matched and Stratified Samples](http://amstat.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01621459.1975.10480314)
3. [A Comparative Study of Conditional Maximum Likelihood Estimation of a Common Odds Ratio](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2531163?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)

Comment: It'd be useful to summarize at least a little what those references have to say.

Comment: @Scortchi, agreed. I've been busy with work and only had the chance to read through the first page or two of each. I'll add a summary of each this weekend.

Comment: @Jon If you could, it would be useful to add that brief summary

Comment: @Jon I only asked one question. It was bli who added a second question 4 years after I posted my original question. I'm not reversing bli's annoying edit as you referenced the second question, but I'm not sure how to accept an answer any more.